# ipad/iphone, Secure app Distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, provisioning

i have developed a ipad static presentation application, here i doesnt want to submit it to the app store.
this app users not even exceed 100.

here my requirement is if user is connected to the internet means app should hit the apple developer site and it should check whether the connected device id is added to current provisioning profile. if device id is there means it should execute the application further else it should not execute.

is there any way to implement this...

is apple is providing any API's to perform these things...?..

any suggestion pls..?

Answer (score 2):

The method you propose is not possible, but close.

When you sign the application for ad-hoc distribution, you sign it with a provisioning profile. This profile contains the ID:s of the devices that the application will run on. It will not even install on other devices.

Take a look at how to do ad-hoc distribution. For less than 100 devices, it is possible to accomplish exactly what you need. The app can then be distributed wirelessly (from a web page) to the authorized devices.

Comment: thanks Borg, here my problem is if a person is run away with device which app is installed means. he shouldnt able to access the application. so how to implement this..

Comment: Possibly you could require a password for launching the app, which the new owner wouldn't know. Or you could require the app to log in on a server over the network...